# Get FirstName in Invoice Email in Magento

Tags: magento, invoices

I need to use the greeting as "Hello customer_firstname" in Invoice emails.

In the Invoice email template file invoice_new.html file, the following line is written, however it is showing the full name of the customer.

```
Hello, {{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerFirstname()}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution where I modified the class **Mage_Sales_Model_Order** a little and added a new Method called "getCustomerOnlyFirstName" as shown below ::

The class "Mage_Sales_Model_Order" can be found in **app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order.php** path..

```
public function getCustomerOnlyFirstName()
{
  $name = trim($this->getCustomerName());
  $pos = strpos($name," ");

  if($pos !== false) /// FirstName can be extracted
  {
     $name = trim(substr( $name, 0, $pos ));
  }

  return $name; 
}
```

And in Email templates ( invoice_new.html and invoice_new_guest.html ), I had to write the following lines to get the things done ...

```
Hello, {{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerOnlyFirstName()}}
```

It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
{{var order.getCustomerFirstname()}}

<h4>Ficou com d&uacute;vidas? {{var order.getCustomerFirstname()}}</h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<p class="greeting">{{trans "%name," name=$order.getBillingAddress().getFirstname()}}</p>
```